# What are the differences between the DWT and the MODWT?

Tags: wavelet, transform, dwt

What are the differences between the DWT (Discrete Wavelet Transform), which is the most classical algorithm and the Maximum Overlap Discrete Wavelet Trasnform (MODWT)?

Both these algorithm are available in MATLAB. As far as I know MODTW is more suite for multi-resolution analysis, whereas DWT is more useful for signal de-noising and compression.

Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from "wavelet methods for time series analysis"
[image: From]

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Given that, do you think that MODTW is better for multi-resolution analysis? And what about wavelet de-noising?